# Check if the String is palindrome using recursion not working even if the logic of the code seems to be correct

Tags: c, string, algorithm, recursion, palindrome

This is my code code for checking if the given string is a palindrome or not, using recursion:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

bool ispalindrome(char A[],int low,int high) {
    if (low>=high)
        return true;
    else {
        return ((A[low] == A[high]) && ispalindrome(A,low+1,high-1));
    }
}

int main() {
    char A[100];
    bool result;
    int len;
    printf("Enter the string");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", A);
    len=strlen(A);
    result=ispalindrome(A,0,len-1);
    if(result==true)
        printf("Yes");
    else
        printf("No");
    return 0;
}
```

What is the issue here? The code logic seems to be correct, but the program is printing "no" for palindromic strings.

Comment: I edited your question to fix a bit the indentation and added the missing closing brace which I suppose is in your code. Could you please provide the input for which you get the wrong result?

Comment: Your logic seems correct to me. You sure it was not something else?

Comment: As spotted before, gives example which does work and examples which does not work.

Comment: @trincot . Thank you sir . I am getting incorrect output for 'level', 'abba', In geenral, for all the palindromic inputs i am getting incorrect output

Comment: @Ptit Xav  it works for strings that are not palindrome , but for strings like, 'level', 'ABBA' it prints that these strings are not palindrome.

Comment: I tested your code with your examples and have no problem. Can you debug or print the length A, just in case a \r (or other) character is added by your computer.

Comment: @Ptit Xav Yes  sir, for string 'abba' i have printed the length its showing 5, but i've made sure in my code that i send the length-1 to the function that checks for the palindrome string.

Comment: You should have strlen(A) = 4 for ABBA. That means that A contains a character that is not desired. You can print it with printf("Last A char ascii code: %d\n",A([strlen(A)-1]); The len-1 parameter is only because in string with length n, you access data from 0 to n-1.

Comment: @Ptit Xav Sir i get what you are saying, but i am still unable to figure out where i went wrong in the code, and what changes am i supposed to make?when i print in the manner given by you the character it prints is the last character of 'abba' i.e, a

Comment: @PRIYANKACHETTRI may be in the scant add « \r » in characters to exclude.